# Linux Wi-Fi Drivers for New Dell XPS 15

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, drivers

**Model:** New Dell XPS 15 7590

**OS Version:** Ubuntu 19.04

**Kernel Version:** 5.0.25/5.1.21 (I've tried all below on both versions, neither resolves the issue)

**The Problem:**

Ubuntu does not detect a Wi-Fi card attached to the computer, seemingly because of driver issues. `lspci` says that the Network Controller is an `Intel Corporation Device 2723 (rev 1a)`, and `lshw -c network` confirms that it is an Intel Corporation device that is marked `UNCLAIMED`, implying a driver issue of some kind. `rfkill` shows a working Bluetooth device, but doesn't list anything for Wi-Fi.

Interestingly, the Dell website says the card is a Killer Wi-Fi 6 AX1650 (2x2), and it functions well on the Windows install in this machine (after installing appropriate Killer drivers).

**Attempted Fixes:**

I've scoured the internet for hours. What I've tried:

1. Upgrading to Kernel version 5.1 (Problem Persisted)
2. Upgrading to 5.2 (Persisted, later uninstalled 5.2)
3. Forcing reinstall of `linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)`, which errored out on all kernel versions. On 5.0, it fails to install `broadcom-sta-dkms`, as the module, for some reason, tries to initialize installation for kernel version 5.2.8, despite uninstallation of 5.2. On 5.1 and 5.2, `apt` can't find the package.
4. Purging `bcmw-kernel-source` and installing `ubuntu-restricted-extras`. Fails for the same `broadcom-sta-dkms` issues as above.
5. Everything else I've come across so far. Nothing has worked, and I am officially lost.

Any ideas? Is this Wi-Fi card just incompatible with current Linux?

Comment: I'd test temporarily with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (yes, going backwards) on a USB drive (no need to install) to see if the issue is the newer OS. The LTS versions are pretty good about including drivers. Another option is a WiFi dongle, but that *should not* be needed!

Comment: What is the vendor:product ID from `lspci -nn` (or `lspci -tvnn`)?

Comment: @DrMoishe I initially did install 18.04, I forgot that in my original post, and it didn't work. I went up to 19.04 in hopes that the newer version would have the drivers for a new computer, but no dice.

Comment: @grawity ```lspci -nn | grep Network``` returns ```3b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2723] (rev 1a)```

Comment: Did you buy the developers edition where ubuntu is supported by Dell?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen No, just the normal. But the marked solution does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have tried this one: https://support.killernetworking.com/knowledge-base/killer-ax1650-in-debian-ubuntu-16-04/

Just got my new XPS 15 and still figuring things out. You're further along with OS installed, give it a shot maybe

Comment: Thank you! Of all the things I read online, looks like I missed this. Quick caution though: the article notes a patch that needs to be made, but the article is outdated and the patch has been pushed to master, no need to try to apply it yourself.

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks for confirming, I'm done with the installation and off to fix the wifi! :))

Comment: Link dead, goes to an Intel page.

Answer (score 0):

This [solution](https://superuser.com/a/1471414/605299) works for me except that Ubuntu - at least 18.04 - does not come initially with `make`. As I had no Ethernet port and obviously no Wi-fi, I had to install `build-essential` which provides `make` offline.

So to install it I took it from Ubuntu ISO file, as `build-essential` is not installed but is available.

```
sudo mkdir /media/cdrom
sudo mount /home/bernard/Downloads/ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso /media/cdrom
sudo apt-cdrom -d=/media/cdrom add -m
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential
```

Don't forget to remove it after by commenting out the cdrom line in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

If the driver is on a USB stick, you may run into permission issues while running `make` commands if you use filesystems that don't really support permissions.